Draw on the windows 11 wallpaper in C++/Qt
I'm trying to use Qt and C++ to draw a window on the windows desktop, between the icons and the wallpaper, to make that window into a wallpaper.
This simplified version of my program makes a window that's inactive, always in the background, and that does not catch inputs, at the size and position of the first screen it finds:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QWindow>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MainWindow(QRect geometry, QWidget* parent = nullptr): QMainWindow(parent) {
            setGeometry(geometry);
            setWindowFlags(
                Qt::FramelessWindowHint |
                Qt::WindowTransparentForInput |
                Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint
            );
            HWND hWnd = (HWND)winId();
            LONG_PTR exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
        }
        ~MainWindow(){}

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
            QPainter painter(this);
            painter.fillRect(geometry(), QColor(0, 50, 120));
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(a.screens().at(0)->geometry());
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

The issue here is that despite being under all windows and letting inputs go through it (including right clicks on the desktop), it's still above the desktop icons.
My main sources for this were:

Draw on Windows 10 wallpaper in C++
How to create a QWidget with a HWND as parent?
QWidget::createWindowContainer
QWindow::fromWinId

The first shows how to get a HWND to the wallpaper.
The second shows how to use a HWND as a parent for a QWidget, but it's for Qt <5, and I'm using Qt 6.6.1.
It used QWidget::create, which is now deprecated and the Qt docs say it should be replaced with QWidget::createWindowContainer and QWindow::fromWinId. However I don't really understand the ins and outs of Qt, and I'm really out of my depth when it comes to the Windows API. I barely understand what a HWND actually is.
With the help of a friendly robot, I was able to come up with this:
// Both functions are from the first link
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, L"SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
    HWND* ret = (HWND*)lParam;

    if (p)
    {
        // Gets the WorkerW Window after the current one.
        *ret = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, L"WorkerW", NULL);
    }
    return true;
}

HWND get_wallpaper_window()
{
    // Fetch the Progman window
    HWND progman = FindWindow(L"ProgMan", NULL);
    // progman = FindWindow(L"MozillaWindowClass", 0);
    // Send 0x052C to Progman. This message directs Progman to spawn a
    // WorkerW behind the desktop icons. If it is already there, nothing
    // happens.
    SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, nullptr);
    // We enumerate all Windows, until we find one that has the SHELLDLL_DefView
    // as a child.
    // If we found that window, we take its next sibling and assign it to workerw.
    HWND wallpaper_hwnd = nullptr;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&wallpaper_hwnd);
    // Return the handle you're looking for.
    return wallpaper_hwnd;
}

// My code
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    HWND wallpaper_hwnd = get_wallpaper_window();
    QWindow* wallpaper_window = QWindow::fromWinId((WId)wallpaper_hwnd);
    QWidget* wallpaper_widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(wallpaper_window);

    MainWindow w(a.screens().at(0)->geometry(), wallpaper_widget);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

It's unclear what's actually happening. Visually, nothing. The window just doesn't show up anymore, but it looks like the program doesn't crash.
I have high suspicions that I'm just using the HWND from get_wallpaper_window wrong.
Additional info:

wallpaper_window's geometry (x, y, width, height) is 1200, 720, 160, 160
wallpaper_widget's geometry is 0, 0, 640, 480
My display's geometry is 0, 0, 1600, 2560
In the first version of the code, without the wallpaper as a parent, sometimes when I click on the window, the desktop icons are briefly visible over the window.

Edit: It seems what I'm trying to do is not possible as I intended. According to the answer to this post, I should "[subclass the ListView] to intercept its WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT messages". That probably wouldn't involve Qt even if I wanted to. I'll have to look at how to do that.

Windows are not physically under or over other windows, like a stack of papers. There is only a painting priority, which is implemented by painting the backdrop first and then the immediate descendents of the backdrop, recursively. There are some expectations of how this will turn out, and they might also be met other ways. That could explain Win11 differing from Win10. And then since you're violating expectations, you might be breaking some Win11 optimization. Did you try painting with GetDC(0) ?

"progman" was considered deprecated and theoretically unused since Vista. Chances are that even its "window name" still result in a (theoretically) geometry made available from the OS (for partial backward compatibility), it doesn't provide the same undocumented API. Also, remember that createWindowContainer() was never intended to provide full support to any non-Qt window. Its primary official purpose is to allow embedding of windows belonging to other Qt based processes. Using it with any other "window" that isn't created by Qt is not officially supported and may just work by luck.

@cardiffspaceman thanks for taking the time. I'm sorry but I really don't know anything about the windows API. What do I with the result of GetDC?
Also, I originally asked for win11 because it's what I was on but I'm writing the software for win10, so if you have an idea that only works for win10 i'm all ears

@Rijaja You would have to look at the docs of QT, the API that you used to get the HWND. Or you could use the result of GetDC(NULL) which is a DC, device context, which you can use with Win32 directly.

Microsoft does not provide a feature to "use an application's window image as the wallpaper," so you'll have to find a way to achieve this without official support. There are some open-source dynamic wallpaper projects available online, so you may need to study how they are implemented.
Typically, an application should only perform drawing operations within its own window, and should not send messages to other applications that rely on their internal implementations unless it is explicitly documented (that's the purpose of APIs. However, sometimes people can't find the necessary API and resort to reverse engineering...).
The approach I took is to make the window image above the icons transparent. This can be achieved using Layered Windows and MaskBlt when the original wallpaper is a solid color.
Below is a dynamic wallpaper I created, which is a Win32-based program (because I’m not familiar with Qt):
summary:
Use CreateWindowEx to create a window with the following extended window styles:
WS_EX_LAYERED (allows transparency)
WS_EX_TRANSPARENT (lets inputs go through it)
WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
Call SetLayeredWindowAttributes and set pure black pixels to be transparent (this will make all pure black areas transparent; if you choose another color, you'll need to change the subsequent steps where black pixels are filled to use that color).
Draw the image in a memory DC (in my program, I directly used a pre-existing bitmap image), then create a monochrome mask bitmap using the original wallpaper image. After that, use MaskBlt to transfer the image from the memory DC to the window, making the areas containing the icons' images black.
// This program must declare DPI awareness
#include<thread>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include"resource.h"
COLORREF GetBackgroundColor();// Get the color of the original wallpaper
std::atomic<bool> exitflag(false);//need C++20

std::thread paintThread;
// Window painting function
void Paint(HWND hwnd, int windowWidth, int windowHeight, HWND background, COLORREF backgroundColor) {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    SetStretchBltMode(memDC, HALFTONE);

    struct IMAGES {
        DWORD duration;
        HBITMAP image = NULL;
        ~IMAGES() {
            DeleteObject(image);
        }
    }images[6]{ {1000},{1000},{1000},{1000},{1000},{1000} };//6 bitmaps used for composing animation
    const int rc[6]{ IDB_BITMAP1 ,IDB_BITMAP2 ,IDB_BITMAP3 ,IDB_BITMAP4 ,IDB_BITMAP5 ,IDB_BITMAP6 };
    const SIZE rcbitmapsize = { 1920,1440 };// These values are the dimensions of "my" bitmaps

    // The resource bitmaps will be pre-stretched to this size, which is also the size of the window
    const SIZE bitmapsize = ((double)rcbitmapsize.cx / rcbitmapsize.cy) > ((double)windowWidth / windowHeight) ?
        SIZE{ windowWidth, MulDiv(rcbitmapsize.cy, windowWidth, rcbitmapsize.cx) } : SIZE{ MulDiv(rcbitmapsize.cx, windowHeight, rcbitmapsize.cy),windowHeight };
    {
        HDC tempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        // Load bitmaps from resources and pre-stretch them to bitmapsize
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            HBITMAP temp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(rc[i]),
                IMAGE_BITMAP,
                0, 0,
                LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            );
            auto stockbitmap = SelectObject(tempDC, temp);
            images[i].image = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy);
            SelectObject(memDC, images[i].image);
            StretchBlt(memDC, 0, 0, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy, tempDC, 0, 0, rcbitmapsize.cx, rcbitmapsize.cy, SRCCOPY);
            SelectObject(tempDC, stockbitmap);
            DeleteObject(temp);
        }
        DeleteDC(tempDC);
    }
    // DC of the original wallpaper
    HDC backgroundDC = GetDC(background);

    // Set the background color, this color will convert to 0 when BitBlt to a monochrome bitmap
    SetBkColor(backgroundDC, backgroundColor);

    HDC maskDC = CreateCompatibleDC(backgroundDC);
    HBITMAP maskBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(maskDC, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy);// Monochrome bitmap
    SelectObject(maskDC, maskBitmap);

    // The position of the window on the screen
    int x = (windowWidth - bitmapsize.cx) / 2;
    int y = (windowHeight - bitmapsize.cy) / 2;

    // Resize and display the window
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, x, y, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);// The window is visible at this point (but has no content yet)
    while (!exitflag) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6 && !exitflag; ++i) {

            // Create the mask bitmap
            BitBlt(maskDC, 0, 0, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy, backgroundDC, x, y, SRCCOPY);

            // Use ready-made bitmaps as images
            SelectObject(memDC, images[i].image);

            // Apply the mask bitmap while transferring the image of the memory DC to the window
            MaskBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmapsize.cx, bitmapsize.cy, memDC, 0, 0, maskBitmap, 0, 0, MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY, BLACKNESS));

            Sleep(images[i].duration);
        }
        // Keep the window at the bottom
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
    // Cleanup
    DeleteDC(maskDC);
    DeleteObject(maskBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(background, backgroundDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}

// Window procedure function
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        exitflag.store(true);
        paintThread.join();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //Get the HWND of original wallpaper
    HWND desktopHWND = GetShellWindow();
    HWND desktopHWND2 = FindWindowEx(desktopHWND, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    HWND desktopHWND3 = FindWindowEx(desktopHWND2, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (desktopHWND2 == NULL || desktopHWND3 == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    //Get the color of original wallpaper
    COLORREF backgroundColor = GetBackgroundColor();
    if (backgroundColor == CLR_INVALID) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Register the window class
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"MyWallpaperClass";
    WNDCLASSW wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;// No background painting
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    // Create the window
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE, // Extended window styles
        CLASS_NAME,                                           // Window class name
        L"Miku wallpaper",                                    // Window title
        WS_POPUP,                                             // Window style
        0, 0,                                                 // Window position
        320, 240,                                             // Window size
        NULL,                                                 // Parent window
        NULL,                                                 // Menu
        hInstance,                                            // Instance handle
        NULL                                                  // Additional parameters
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Set the window transparency
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), NULL, LWA_COLORKEY);//set pure black pixels to be transparent

    // There's no ShowWindow, so the window is still invisible at this point
    // Even if ShowWindow is called here, the window won't have any visuals until the painting starts since wc.hbrBackground is NULL

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(desktopHWND, &rect);

    // Use a separate thread to handle the image display work, instead of handling the WM_PAINT message
    paintThread = std::thread(Paint, hwnd, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, desktopHWND3, backgroundColor);

    // Message pump
    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
// Get the wallpaper color; if the wallpaper is not solid, return CLR_INVALID
// This function was generated by ChatGPT
COLORREF GetBackgroundColor()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    COLORREF color = CLR_INVALID;// Default to the color used in case of failure

    // Attempt to open the registry key storing the wallpaper color
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Control Panel\\Desktop"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        TCHAR szWallpaper[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(szWallpaper);

        // Read the "Wallpaper" key value to check if an image wallpaper exists
        if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("Wallpaper"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szWallpaper, &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Check if it's an empty string (i.e., a solid color wallpaper)
            if (_tcslen(szWallpaper) == 0)
            {
                // If the wallpaper is solid, further check the wallpaper color
                RegCloseKey(hKey);// Close the current registry key

                if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Control Panel\\Colors"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    TCHAR szColor[16];
                    dwSize = sizeof(szColor);

                    // Read the "Background" key value
                    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("Background"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szColor, &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        int r, g, b;
                        // Parse the color string (RGB values)
                        if (_stscanf_s(szColor, TEXT("%d %d %d"), &r, &g, &b) == 3)
                        {
                            color = RGB(r, g, b);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return color;
}

You can download the complete Visual Studio project from the following link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/120gAn-n0aR3OXpSjo1OSx2r6C4Npwivb
Other Notes:
The original wallpaper must be a solid color and must not have been changed to anything other than a solid color since the computer was started.
The image changes on the original wallpaper will only be reflected the next time the dynamic wallpaper redraws the image.
If the dynamic wallpaper image is too close in color to the icons' text, the icons' text might become difficult to read.
This dynamic wallpaper will temporarily disappear when the user presses Windows + D to show the desktop, and it will reappear when any window is activated.(Show Desktop minimizing all the windows that can be minimized, then takes the desktop and "raises" it to the top of the window stack so that no other windows cover it.)
This dynamic wallpaper does not support multiple monitors and will encounter errors if the screen resolution is changed.
This dynamic wallpaper can only be closed via the Task Manager.(Unless someone manages to send it a WM_CLOSE message)
The dynamic wallpaper will consume additional GPU resources. Also, this program uses two common device contexts that are never released. (Applications should always obtain a DC only when drawing, and release the DC as soon as possible after drawing is complete. A large number of unreleased Common DCs will exhaust the DC cache and make drawing slow)
Please do not run more than one instance at a time.

Thanks for taking your time to answer this. I'll take a look at what I mentioned in my original post's edit and at other open-source wallpaper programs, as you suggested. Unfortunately your solution won't work for me because of the solid color requirement (my admins decided to force a wallpaper on us, which is the entire reason i'm doing this in the first place)

@Rijaja
I edited the beginning of my answer because I figured out how drawing between the icons and the wallpaper works.

Once you obtain the HWND of a window, you can use the GetDC function to get a device context (DC) that allows you to draw on the window.
Yes, that's right—you can directly draw on someone else's window. This won't cause any harm to the target window. The only potential impact is that the process might notice some images in its window that it never drew. But then again, no program ever checks its window for suspicious images.
The only thing to keep in mind is that the owner of that window may also draw on it at any time, and any drawing that occurs later will overwrite the previous drawings.
You have found a window and can achieve your needs by drawing directly on it. Do you still need to find a way to create a window underneath using Qt? So, forget about Qt for now. Is there anything specifically forcing you to use Qt? If it's just about displaying static images, using traditional WinAPI is not too difficult.
If you're not sure where to start, SetPixel is a good place. Although it's inefficient, it's easy to understand how to use it.
    HWND progman = get_wallpaper_window();
    HDC hdc= GetDC(progman);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j) {
            SetPixel(hdc,i,j,RGB(0,255,0));
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(progman, hdc);

Next, you can try using BitBlt to copy the image content from the left side of the screen to the right.
    while (true) {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        BitBlt(hdc, 1000, 0, 800, 800, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
        Sleep(100);
    }

Finally, you can attempt to load a bitmap into a memory DC (BMP files, despite their large size, can be used immediately without extra work upon loading) and then transfer the image from the memory DC to the screen.
If you need to resize the bitmap, you can use StretchBlt. If you notice color distortion when using StretchBlt, use SetStretchBltMode to set COLORONCOLOR (faster) or HALFTONE (slower but higher quality).
If the image will be reused, it is recommended to save the resized image and then use BitBlt instead of resizing it every time with StretchBlt.
You can perform these operations using a different HDC or use other BitBlt raster-operation codes and observe the effects.
Other Notes:
All the drawing you perform will persist even after your program terminates, until another drawing operation overwrites it or the window is destroyed.
If you don't see the expected result, check if the function succeeded, as the window isn't yours.
Some hardware-accelerated windows (like Google Chrome, your game window, etc.) cannot be interacted with using GDI. The function might succeed, but the expected result won't appear.
A common device context should be released with ReleaseDC() when not in use to return it to the DC cache, and you should get it again the next time you need to use it.
If there's anything you don't understand, you can ask a generative AI (like ChatGPT). Up to this point, the content should be fairly straightforward.
If you need more complex functionality, you may still need to create your own window.
